# React onPaste windows does not get called but works on Mac

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to use `onPaste` attribute in react version 16.3.1 and it works perfectly on Ubuntu and Mac but does not work on windows. To be specific, `onChange` gets called instead when I paste something. I'm not doing any `preventDefault` or something. If I edit raw html in chrome and add `onpaste="alert('onpaste called')"` and then I paste something, it works. I'm not sure what is the problem.

```
<input onChange={(event) => handleOnChange(event)}
       value={defaultValue}
       onPaste={event => handleOnPaste(event)}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In which browser are you testing on Windows?
Remember that `onpaste` has limited browser compatibility -> 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/onpaste

Are you using the same version of chrome in all machines?